# Relation between Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a function such that the set of it's points of discontinuities have measure $0$ and such that the improper Riemann integral $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$ exists. It is true that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable in $[0,1]$ ? My guess is that this is true, but I don't know how to give an argument.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: For $f$ to be Lebesgue integrable, you need both $f_+$ and $f_-$ to be finite. But $f$ can be Riemann integrable because of cancellations.

Comment: Nice hint, I will try to construct something in that sense.

Comment: A bounded function $f$ defined on an interval is Riemann integrable iff $f$ is continuous a.e., and if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, and its Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral are equal. You can use step functions $\sigma_k$ and $\tau_k$.

Comment: If you are lost in constructing a counter-example, searching on this community will provide nice ones, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3432355/9340) for instance.

Comment: No. [Here is a counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4194453/568204) which shows that the improper RIemann integral $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1f$ could exist in $\Bbb{R}$ without $f\in L^1([0,1])$.

Comment: @SangchulLee WOW, nice counterexamples, not so easy to construct these functions alone.

Comment: @VictorRafael: I don't think your statement is true in general. $\int^1_0\frac{\sin(u^{-1})}{u}\,du$ as an improper intergral exists, yet $u\mapsto\frac{\sin(u^{-1})}{u}$ is not Lebesgue integrable (it is however continuous on $[0,1]$ with the exception of $x=0$.

$du=-u^2\,dt$

$\int^\infty_1\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt\stackrel{u=1/t}{=}\int^1_0\frac{\sin(u^{-1})}{u}\,du$

Comment: As phrased I don't think the question makes sense.  Do you mean an improper $f:(0,1)$?  If $f$ is actually defined on $[0,1]$, I'm pretty sure it can't be improper.....

Comment: Do not write $\int f(x)dx <\infty$ to say that $f$ is  integrable. This is a huge mistake which many students make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an counter-example:

Define $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=n(-1)^n$ if $\frac{1}{n+1}
<x\leq \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$. Then $f$ has an countable points of discontinuities, and then the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure $0$. Now we have:
$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}=\log2. $$

Showing that $f$ has improper Riemann integral. But

$$\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}=+\infty.$$

Concluding that $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable.